# Disable Spring Boot AutoConfiguration for transitive dependencies

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

I've created a Spring Boot project for mocking soap services - it has a dependency on         `org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security` for handling ws-sec headers, which introduces a  transitive dependency on `org.springframework.security:spring-security-core`

Having this on my runtime classpath causes Spring Boot to think I want web security enabled, and even if I disable it with `security.basic.enabled = false` I end up getting a runtime ClassNotFound exception unless I also add:

```
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:$springSecurityVersion")
```

to my runtime classpath. Is there any way to indicate to Boot that, although it's on the classpath at runtime, that I truly want nothing to do with Spring Security, and to cause it to not require these additional dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want nothing to do with it, maybe it's actually an optional dependency (and could be excluded)? Failing that you can add excludes to the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (e.g. see the javadoc for detail). You would want to exclude `SecurityAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response @DaveSyer! That doesn't seem to work though, I'm still getting: 

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/AuthenticationSwitchUserEvent` on startup.

My BaseApplicationConfig.groovy looks like:

`@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=[SecurityAutoConfiguration])
@Slf4j
@ComponentScan(basePackages=["com.test.mocky"])
@CompileStatic
public class BaseApplicationConfig {...}`

Comment: What version of Spring Boot is that?

Comment: Please try a snapshot

Comment: Same errors as above using the latest Snapshot 20140212

Comment: OK, can you share a project on github (or similar)?

Comment: Dave, i'll try to create a minimum project that i can share... should I create a JIRA or keep the discussion here?

Comment: Create an issue if you want to (no JIRA, just [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) for Boot). Not sure if it's an issue yet, but happy to discuss there anyway.

Comment: Thanks! i'll do so if i can recreate with minimal project

Comment: Thanks @Dave - i've submitted a github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/363)
and a minimal [project](https://github.com/madorb/spring-boot-autoconfig-issue)

Comment: Here is a link to Spring documentation on disabling auto-configuration https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration