# How to tell which spring-boot Autoconfigurers have been activated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

in a Spring Boot application, I am worried about AutoConfigurations also being triggered by transitive dependencies.

Specific autoconfigurations can be switched off as described here [Disable Spring Boot AutoConfiguration for transitive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710450/disable-spring-boot-autoconfiguration-for-transitive-dependencies)

But how can I know which AutoConfigurations have been activated? There does not seem to be a consistent logging of activations on startup. I just noticed VelocityAutoConfiguration has been activated in my application, I can disable that, but it makes me worried about other autoconfigurations being activated without my knowledge and intent.

Comment: hm, I guess the /autoconfig endpoint can help with that...

Comment: But I see Configurers mentioned both in positive and negative matches, so how to tell whether a single positive match is sufficient for activation?

Comment: Anything in the "positive" list is activated, anything in the "negative" list is not. Simples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely pay attention to those transitive dependencies.

There's about 5 or more different ways you can enable or view the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` report. The report will show you:

1. what's enabled
2. what's disabled
3. what's excluded
4. configurations that are unconditional

As an application argument

```
--debug
```

As a VM argument

```
-Ddebug
```

As an environment variable

```
export DEBUG=true // UNIX based
set DEBUG=true // Windows based
```

By adding a property to your `application.properties`

```
debug=true
```

Adjusting the log level in your `application.properties`

```
logging.level.=debug
```

Adjusting the log level of the report generator class in your `application.properties`

**Spring Boot 1.x**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer=debug
```

**Spring Boot 2.x**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener=debug
```

Comment: The reporting class has been renamed to `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener` in Spring Boot 2.

Answer (score 3):

Starting your application with `--debug` will log an auto-configuration report that shows every auto-configuration class that was considered during startup and whether or not it was activated. Every class listed as a positive match has been activated and every class listed as a negative match has not been activated.

If your application's using Spring Boot's Actuator (it has a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator`), then, as mentioned in the question comments, you can also access the report over HTTP using the `/autoconfig` endpoint.

Comment: I have the actuator dependencies as a part of my maven dependencies, I see actuator in `negative matches` in console. Though I am able to reach to `/info`,`/profile` and some other, but unable to do so for urls like `/application`,`/health`. Any specific reason why is this so.

Comment: Only a handful of endpoints are accessible over HTTP by default so that things are secure by default. You have to opt in to the others.